# Ruby on Rails acquire client IP address on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First off, I am very new to Ruby on Rails. I have a user object and a form for ex.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   f.submit #call something 
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form and want to have the user's IP address added to the database in which the user's values are stored. Not quite sure what I need to call in order to do so on f.sumbit. Maybe going the completely wrong  way about it, open to ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ip address is available to controllers as the `remote_ip` field of the `request` instance, e.g.:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    ip = request.remote_ip
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the IP on the client side, you have to do it in the server side. To access the IP just consult it in the controller like:

```
request.remote_ip
```